# Calculation of an inverse Mellin transfrom

Tags: integration, complex-integration, mellin-transform

I  would like to calculate the inverse Mellin transform of the following function ($a$ being a real positive number):

$$f(s)=(2 \pi)^{-s} \cos(\frac{\pi s}{2}) \Gamma(s) \frac{1-a^{s-1}}{1-a^{-s}}.$$

How can I calculate it?

Inverse is the following integral ($\mathcal{Re}(c)>0$):

$$[\mathcal{M}^{-1} f] (x) =\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} (2 \pi)^{-s} \cos(\frac{\pi s}{2}) \Gamma(s) \frac{1-a^{s-1}}{1-a^{-s}} x^{-s} ds.$$

(I do not have Matlab to ask for a result...)

Comment: What are $a$ and $c$ ? For $b >0,\Re(s) > 0$ and by analytic continuation $\Re(b)>0,\Re(s) > 0$ we have $\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-bx}dx= b^{-s}\Gamma(s)$ so $\mathcal{M}^{-1}(2 \cos(r s) \Gamma(s)) = e^{-e^{ir} x}+e^{-e^{-ir} x}$ for $r=\pi/2-\epsilon$ and $c > 0$.

Comment: The integrand is not $L^1$ nor $L^2$ on the vertical line $\Re(s)=c>0$, the inverse Mellin transform exists in the sense of distributions. The right approach is clearly to replace $\cos(\pi s/2)$ by $\cos(rs)$ and to let $r\to \pi/2$.